# Uppercase Visual Studio 2013 project template $itemname$

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Is there a way to uppercase Visual Studio project template parameters?

For example change `$safeprojectname$` to UPPERCASE.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a [template wizard extension.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.templatewizard.iwizard.aspx) In the [RunStarted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.templatewizard.iwizard.runstarted.aspx) method

you get a dictionary with the list of standard parameters which should be replaced as

```
Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary
```

You can now go over the dictionary and do the ToUpper or anything else by yourself:

```
foreach (var key in replacementsDictionary.Keys)
{
    replacementsDictionary[key] = replacementsDictionary[key].ToUpper();
}
```