# Uppercase Visual Studio itemTemplate Parameters

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, itemtemplate

I want to have a custom template item in VS2015.
I've created what I need, but I want to adjust some "look and feel" of the template.
The template for a c++ header looks like this:

```
#ifndef $safeitemname$_$guid1$
#define $safeitemname$_$guid1$


namespace $safeprojectname$
{

class $safeitemname$ final
{

public:
    $safeitemname$();       

    ~$safeitemname$();              

    $safeitemname$( const $safeitemname$& ) = delete;    

    $safeitemname$& operator=( const $safeitemname$& ) = delete;


private:    

};    

}    

#endif
```

What I want to achieve is: uppercase `$safeitemname$` and `$guid$` in the define, and also underscored `$guid$`.

It is possible? How can I do it?

I saw another thread about something similar, but with no answer:
[Uppercase Visual Studio 2013 project template $itemname$](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171992/upercase-visual-studio-2013-project-template-itemname)

Comment: So that you provide `abc` for `$safeitemname$` but as it is resolved you get `ABC`? Is that what you want?

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi I want uppercase of `$safeitemname$` just in the `#define` section in this example above. In other parts, I want it lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such feature like that. Several workarounds come to my mind, though:

1. Use a .bat file to create new classes. Actually I'm doing this in my project.
2. Live with non-uppercase `#defines`. It is used in one place only and the GUID makes it clear that it is not a class name. So what?
3. Use `#pragma once`. [Many compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once#Portability) support this. I use this in addition to 1.
4. You could provide two variables like `$safeitemname$` for the class name and `$include_guard$` for the `#define` macro.